# C++ Error: Class has-a-relationship with Struct in Same Header File

Tags: c++, eclipse, compiler-errors

I'm defining a C++ header file, and for some reason the class I'm creating gives an error when I try to refer to a struct which is defined in the very same file, along with an enumeration class I created.

I'm pretty to new to C++, though I have some experience with Java and C#. Even then, my programming experience is relatively low. Am I initializing the reference wrong? Should I be placing both the struct and the enum in a separate header file?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

class Character 
{
private:

    Stats stats; //<--error: "Type 'Stats' could not be resolved."

public:




};

struct Stats
{
    int strength;
    int intelligence;
    int endurance;
    int speed;
    int agility;
    int luck;
};

enum Race 
{
    NONE,
    HUMAN,
    ALIEN,
    ANDROID
};
```

Note: I'm using Eclipse 3.7 (Indigo) for C++, in case that means anything.

Comment: "Am I initializing the reference wrong?"  What reference?  `stats` is not a reference, it is a variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++ is parsed from the top of the file to the bottom; you need to move your `Stats` class definition to above your `Character` class definition.

Comment: @James: Could you mention how it parses files too? It would prove useful for me and Hlooand.

Comment: @Mr.TAMER:  What do you mean by "how it parses files too?"

Comment: As James said, *"[files are] parsed from the top of the file to the bottom"*.

Comment: @James: I mean with which file it starts and when it gets into the included file and... etc.

Comment: @Mr.TAMER:  It is strictly top-to-bottom.  When an include directive is encountered, the entire contents of the specified file are parsed as if they were part of the source file including it.

Comment: Here's the thing, though: I had the files separated from each other before I decided to put them in the same header. When I initialized the variable references to them in the class file (with a direct include path at the top), I still received the same error. Does this mean that I would need to create a .cpp file first, before I create the variable?

Comment: There are limits to what can be accomplished with `#include` and guards. Set your compiler options to check what the preprocessed output looks like, and see whether things are really being defined before use.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ you cannot use something unless it has already been declared.

In your case, `Stats` must not only have been declared but it must have been completely defined.

That said, ALL UPPERCASE IDENTIFIERS are commonly reserved for macros. Don't use them for constants. Using them for constants is an aggressive attack on the eyes of anyone reading the code, it risks inadvertent text replacement, and it reduces an already small set of choices for macro names. It's a Java-ism. It works in Java because Java does not have a preprocessor (ironically, Java got the convention from C, where it macros were employed as "constants").

Cheers & hth